# Directive with added Listener to ElementRef not working with MatCheckbox 'change' Event

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm having trouble adding a Listener to my custom directive.

I have a Component with a MatCheckbox inside its template. In the MatCheckbox Element I'm using my Custom directive and give an Eventname as a string.

`<mat-checkbox [appDirective]="'change'"> test </mat-checkbox>`

My Directive is simple: Create a Listener to the Element using ElementRef and Renderer2.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDirective]',
})
export class AppDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private dispose?: () => void;

  @Input()
  appDirective = '';

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.elementRef);

    this.dispose = this.renderer.listen(
      this.elementRef.nativeElement,
      // 'change',
      this.appDirective,
      (event) => {
        console.log('renderer2 event listen...');
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.dispose) {
      this.dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

The problem now is that it does not work when I pass in the 'change' Event as the Eventname on the renderer.listen() Function.

I also tried using fromEvent() or addEventListener() with ElementRef but it didn't work either. So this leads me to think the ElementRef is the main problem (not sure though).

I think it has something to do with the MatCheckbox Element having its own 'change' Event, since everytime I use a different Event, for example 'click', it works as expected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4av0R.png)

However the weird part is: If I don't use Renderer2 and ElementRef but instead do it with the HostListener Decorator, it works. Unfortunately I can't use the Input Variable as a Parameter inside the HostListener Decorator.

```
@HostListener('change', ['$event'])
changeEvent(event: Event) {
  console.log('listen...');
}
```

- Why does it work with the HostListener Decorator but not with adding a listener through Renderer2 and ElementRef?
- How can I solve this Problem and would there be any disadvantage in using the 'click' Event instead of the 'change' Event?
- Also, is this behaviour intended from Angular Material, or is it more of a Bug?

I created a small Stackblitz to reproduce this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-33fyww?file=src/app/appDirective.directive.ts

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

check-box internally composed of multiple wrapper elements.When you access ElementRef inside directive It will return checkbox wrapper elements instead of input. Since `change` event only available on input controls it's not working with direct elementRef

use `querySelector` on `ElementRef` to get input element reference and pass it on listen method

```
this.dispose = this.renderer.listen(
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input'),
      // 'change',
      this.appDirective,
      (event) => {
        console.log('renderer2 event listen...');
      }
    );
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k5q8c8?file=src/app/appDirective.directive.ts)

Comment: I think Host-listener on directive gets triggered because "change event will bubble"

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I understand now that the Checkbox is a wrapper and that's why it won't work with ElementRef. Your solution works, but it is more like a specific implementation for the 'change' Event to use querySelector('input'). I want it to be more generic as in being able to use the directive in other Components too and with different Events.  I unfortunately still don't quite understand how the Hostlistener Decorator makes it work. Is there no way of achieving the same thing as Hostlistener by adding the Listener manually?

Comment: Since input change event bubble it is captured by hostlistener, However If you listen blur event using Host listener it would not work